# Knockout view model serialize to db and retrieve

Tags: javascript, json, mvvm, knockout.js

I Have web form which use knockout and i have to implement a new feature to save form as a draft to db and later load again to modify or submit.

Is there any feature on knockout framework to serialize viewmodel to any other form(like json) that i could save to db. then later load it and populate my view  easily.

I know that i can save viewmodel as a json to db and then later i can load it and fill each property on view model like below. but im looking for a feature like serialize and later populate whole viewmodel at once using it.I have lot of properties and i don't want to fill each property by writing a code line as below.

```
var someJSON = /* fetched the saved viewmodel as a json */;
var parsed = JSON.parse(someJSON);

// Update view model properties
viewModel.firstName(parsed.firstName);
viewModel.pets(parsed.pets);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin and replace your code with that one:

```
var someJSON = /* fetched the saved viewmodel as a json */;
var parsed = JSON.parse(someJSON);

// Update view model properties
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapping plugin as other questions have mentioned here, but it definitely isn't perfect.

Most notably, if you have object properties, they won't be converted into observables.

```
var pojo = {
    someStringProperty: 'lol',
    someObjectProperty: { }
};

var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(pojo);

if(!ko.isObservable(vm.someObjectProperty)) console.log('FAIL!');
```

I've looked into forking, but it's kinda not worth it.  I just post-process the object graph looking for properties that *aren't* observable **and** that contain an object and convert them into observable properties.